# Is there a module that would allow me to reorganize the way fields are displayed for a content type form?

Tags: forms

When I create a particular content type, Drupal generates a form for me with all the appropriate data entry fields.

However, the form is not particularly attractive: all the fields are displayed one below the other, but in some cases I would like to be able to display fields side by side, for example.

Does anyone know of a module which would allow me to take control of the way fields for data entry are displayed? I am thinking of something like Display Suite, but for forms.

Comment: nodeformcols (https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeformcols) does some rudimentary reorganizing of forms into two columns and a footer.  css is your friend for a lot of layout options as well.

Comment: I answered a similar question the other day on how to do this using Panels. Check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126652/about-shaping-the-drupal-add-content-pages/126653#126653

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was wondering whether the Field Group module (https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) might also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use css to override the default behaviour, or adjust the css prior to rendering via [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), but simple css is the far simpler approach.